# Моделирование логики кошелька в Java

Tags: java, массивы, строки, int

Всем привет!
У меня вопрос по задаче:нужно реализовать публичный статический метод **getTotalAmount()**, который принимает на вход кошелёк с деньгами в виде массива строк и название валюты. Метод должен возвращать сумму денег указанной валюты.

**Параметры метода:**

**Массив строк**, содержащий купюры разных валют с различными номиналами и
**наименование валюты** (строка из 3-х символов).

Нужно  реализовать данный метод, используя управляющие инструкции.

**Как программа должна работать:**

```
String[] money1 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "usd 10", "rub 50", "usd 5"};

App.getTotalAmount(money1, "usd"); // 16

String[] money2 = {"eur 10", "usd 1", "eur 5", "rub 100", "eur 20", "eur 100", "rub 200"};

App.getTotalAmount(money2, "eur"); // 135

String[] money3 = {"eur 10", "rub 50", "eur 5", "rub 10", "rub 10", "eur 100", "rub 200"};

App.getTotalAmount(money3, "rub"); // 270
```

**Указание к задаче:**

1.Для преобразования строки в целое число используйте метод **parseInt()** класса **Integer**.

2.Для извлечения подстроки из строки используйте метод **substring()**.

```
var text = "some text";
text.substring(1, 6); // "ome t"
text.substring(7); // "xt"
```

**Мой код:**

```
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class Currency {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            }

    public static String getTotalAmount(String[] money,String currency){
        int result=0;
        for(String item: money){
            if(currency==item.substring(0,3)){
                // условие: если указанный курс равен элементу массива, который порезан с 0 - 3 индекс, то

                //прибавляем к счетчику что осталось до конца элемента, преобразовав через parseInt() строку в число
            }
            result=Integer.parseInt(item.substring(4, item.length()));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Я совсем запутался в реализации логики метода getTotalAmount().Помогите мне пожалуйста его реализовать.

Comment: currency в условии надо сравнивать через equals, так как это ссылочные типы. result не перезаписывать, а суммировать. и суммировать его только для определёёного currency

Comment: @siarhei987, точно!Теперь все работает!Благодарю за подсказку!